# Missing ) in paranthetical in JQuery

Tags: jquery

In JQuery ajax Get I am using the following,

```
                    var htm = $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
         url: "http://localhost/cake_1.2.1.8004/index.php/forms/getFormEntry",
                     async: false
                     }).responseText;
                            alert(htm);


    var myObject = eval('(' + htm + ')');

            alert(myObject);
```

My cakePHp code for geFormEntry is

```
       <?php
     $data=array();

     ?>
    <?php foreach ($formid as $r): 


      array_push($data, array('id' => $r['Form']['id']));

       endforeach; 

    echo json_encode(array("attributes" => $data));

  ?>
```

My alert(htm) shows

```
 Array{"attributes":[{"id":"21"},{"id":"20"},{"id":"19"},{"id":"18"},{"id":"17"},{"id":"16"},{"id":"15"},{"id":"14"},{"id":"13"},{"id":"12"},{"id":"11"},{"id":"10"},{"id":"9"},{"id":"8"},{"id":"7"},{"id":"6"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"1"}]}
```

I want to get the attributes id -21..
For that I have used the myObject but showing the error as missing ) in paranthetical

Please suggest how to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You want to be using jQuery's built-in JSON support. Also, you probably don't want to be using synchronous Ajax. Try the following; the function will be called once the Ajax request is complete, and you will have access to a JavaScript object as "json" in the function.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/cake_1.2.1.8004/index.php/forms/getFormEntry", function(json) {
  // access to object here as "json". No need to mess with eval
})
```